# When using Visual Studio and Asp.Net Core, are Unit Testing projects supposed to be in the same Solution as the Production code?

Tags: unit-testing

If I have a Solution with a Project with Production code, where do I do the Unit tests?  Do I put them in a whole new Solution and reference the Release version of my .dll?

I am using Asp.Net Core 1.1, C#.  I have a "regular" MVC project, and I have a Core Web API as well I'd like to test.

I don't think this question is unique for C# or Visual Studio, but that is what I am using.

Comment: You put them into a different *project.*

On your Release build, you can omit the test project, since the production environment will never need it.

Comment: Same solution, right?

Comment: Yes, same solution.

Comment: If you come up with a naming convention one can easily omit the test projects from the package deployment.  Example:  MyProject.dll => MyProjectTests.dll  Any Dll ending in Tests is not included in the package.  We actually deploy several of our test projects as the tests are not unit tests and are run as part of a post deployment activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using the csproj (msbuild) version. At this point, project.json will be going away soon.

Here's a pretty standard project structure.

```
app
  |- app.sln
  |__
  |   |-project 
  |   |__
  |       | project.csproj
  |
  |__
      |-project.tests
      |__
          |-project.tests.csproj
```

Then in your project.tests.csproj, you add a `ProjectReference` element to reference the project under test.

`<ProjectReference Import="..\project\project.csproj" />`